# Running a process that waits on input in the background, without it pausing and without sending input

Tags: linux, bash, redirect, background-process

I have a program that does something like this in order to wait on someone pressing enter in order to quit:

```
spawnThreadAndDoStuff();
System.in.read();
System.exit(0);
```

I want to run it in the background indefinitely from a script, and just go kill it when I want it to end.  I thought reading input from /dev/null would do this, but it doesn't seem to be working.  My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -cp someapp > mylog.log < /dev/null &
```

Am I doing this wrong, or is my approach just way off?  What would the correct way to handle this be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading from `/dev/null` does not work because `read` immediately returns with an end-of-file.

This works for me:

```
(while true; do sleep 10000; done) | java -cp someapp > mylog.log &
```

The first command just sleeps forever, never providing any input.

Comment: I ended up replacing the read with a similar infinite loop, I wouldn't have thought of just piping one like that, that's pretty clever.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing wrong is that input from /dev/null behaves like a 0 byte file, and so the process hits EOF on standard input and quits. If /dev/null could hold a process that expects input, then this would work:

```
$ cat < /dev/null
```

But of course cat exits right away.

You're being bitten by the problem that you have a program with threads which reads from the TTY. As soon as you background it, because it is reading from the TTY, the tty driver sends it a SIGTTIN which stops all of its threads.

I would just rethink that program. If you want a program to work well in the background, do not have it read user input as a termination signal. Get rid of that read and kill it with signals when you want it to stop.

If you want both behaviors (background mode and user-quit mode) then make the program run-time configurable. One way would be simply to detect whether standard input is a TTY device or not. If it is a TTY device, then do the TTY read and quit. If it is not a TTY, then don't read: do an infinite sleep instead.  Then your /dev/null standard input trick should work. /dev/null is not a TTY and so the process will just sleep.

(Do you have the isatty function in Java?)

Comment: The program isn't actually mine, but it is open source.  I was hoping there would be a clean solution that didn't involve changing it.  After I asked, I switched the read to an infinite loop that sleep, similar to what you and  @emilio suggested.  It felt wrong, but I guess it wasn't as unreasonable as I thought.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

command ... &
thePIDofCOMMAND=$!

.... do stuff

kill $thePIDofCOMMAND